# How to delete/update/sort the comments in JPQL statements

Tags: jpa, jpql

I've made a project in class that let's you type in your name and comment, then when you click "Send" it puts the name and comment to the local database and then it displays the name, comment and date in the table below, like this:

[image: Text]

The project uses NetBeans with Java EE, Java SE, GlassFish and local Apache Derby database.

Oh and btw, I'm using VM provided by my uni.

There are 4 main classes inside the project:

`Servlet namai.java`

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jlab1.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@WebServlet(name = "namai", urlPatterns = {"/namai"})
public class namai extends HttpServlet {

    private jlab1.beans.Message msg = new jlab1.beans.Message();

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction utx;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        EntityManager em = null;

        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager(); // sukurti nauja modeliu valdymo objekta
            //Isrinkti esancius komentarus
            List messages = em.createQuery("select m from Message m").getResultList();
            // I uzklausos objekta ideti laikina JavaBean ir EJB pranesimu sarasa
            request.setAttribute("msg", this.msg);
            request.setAttribute("msg_list", messages);
            //Uzklausa perduot i atvaizdavimo lygi
            request.getRequestDispatcher("namai.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new ServletException(e);
        } finally {
            if(em != null){
                em.close();
            }
        }



        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet namai</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet namai at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String l_name = "";
        l_name = request.getParameter("name");
        String l_msg="";
        l_msg = request.getParameter("message");
        //String l_papildomas="";
        String l_papildomas = request.getParameter("papildomas");
        if(l_msg != null && l_name != null){
            this.msg.setName(l_name);
            this.msg.setMsg(l_msg);
            this.msg.setTime(new Date());
            //dadedam papildoma
            //this.msg.setPapildomas(l_papildomas);
            if(request.getParameter("deleteButton") != null){
               //deleteMsg(request, response);
                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                System.out.println("msg id: " + id);
           }

            EntityManager em = null;
//             if(l_name.length() >= 10){
//                 l_name = "Anon";
//             }

            try {
                jlab1.entities.Message e_msg = new jlab1.entities.Message();
                e_msg.setMessage(l_msg);
                e_msg.setName(l_name);
                e_msg.setTime(new Date());
                //dadedam papildoma
                e_msg.setPapildomas(l_papildomas);
                utx.begin();
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
                em.persist(e_msg);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e){
                throw new ServletException(e);
            } finally {
                if(em !=null){
                    em.close();
                }
            }
        }
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

    public void deleteMsg(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
//        System.out.println("msg id: " + id);
        try{
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        //String sql =  + id;
        String queryString = "DELETE m FROM Message m WHERE m.id = " + id;
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);

        query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`JavaBean Message.java`

```
package jlab1.beans;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Message {

    private String name;
    private String msg;
    private Date time;
    private String papildomas;

    public String getPapildomas() {
        return papildomas;
    }

    public void setPapildomas(String papildomas) {
        this.papildomas = papildomas;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Message() {}


}
```

`EJB Message.java`

```
package jlab1.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Message.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Message.findById", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Message.findByName", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Message.findByMessage", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.message = :message"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Message.findByTime", query = "SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.time = :time")})
public class Message implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
     @TableGenerator(name = "MSGPkGen",
            table = "SEQUENCE",
            schema = "APP",
            pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
            pkColumnValue = "MESSAGE",
            valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
            initialValue = 0,
            allocationSize = 1
            )
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MSGPkGen", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 120)
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date time;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "PAPILDOMAS")
    private String papildomas;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Date getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(Date time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPapildomas(){
        return papildomas;
    }

    public void setPapildomas(String papildomas) {
        this.papildomas = papildomas;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Message)) {
            return false;
        }
        Message other = (Message) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jlab1.entities.Message[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

And `namai.jsp`

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title> My first JSP   </title>
                <style>
                    TABLE, TD, TH, TR {
                        border-collapse:collapse;
                        border-width: 1px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-spacing: 5px;
                        padding: 2px 5px;
                    }
                </style>

    </head> 
    <body align="center">       
            <form action="/jlab1" method="POST">            
            Name
            <input type="text" name="name"size="20px">
                        Comment
            <input type="text" name="message"size="20px">

            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form> 
            <hr>
            <div>
                <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                    <jsp:getProperty name="msg" property="name"/>:
                    <jsp:getProperty name="msg" property="msg"/>
                </c:if>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div align="center">
                <table id="messageTable">
                <tr >
                    <th bgcolor=>ID</th>
                    <th bgcolor=>Name</th>
                    <th bgcolor=>Comment</th>
                    <th bgcolor=>Data</th>

                </tr>
                <c:if test="${not empty msg_list}">
                    <c:forEach var="m" begin="0" items="${msg_list}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${m.id}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
                        <td>${m.name}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
                        <td>${m.message}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
                        <td>${m.time}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 
                        <!--<td>${m.papildomas}&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> 

                        <td><button type="submit" name="deleteButton" value="deleteButton" action="${namai.abc}">Delete</button></td>
                        <td><a name="deleteButton" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Message?action=DELETE&id=${m.id}">Delete</a></td> -->
                    </tr> 

                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
                </table>
            </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is add a button that would, for example, delete the selected comment from the database. I've made the button pretty easy by adding `<td><a name="deleteButton" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Message?action=DELETE&id=${m.id}">Delete</a>` to `namai.jsp`, however I just can't make it work.

I've tried a lot of ways to do that, my most recent  is doing something like this:

```
public void deleteMsg(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
//        System.out.println("msg id: " + id);
        try{
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        //String sql =  + id;
        String queryString = "DELETE m FROM Message m WHERE m.id = " + id;
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);

        query.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but this one does not work (malformed query error). I followed a lot of tutorials on youtube, but they all use connection to the DB and statements and I just can't adapt those things on my current project. Tomorrow is a big test from this and I'm really desperate for help. I know that I probably need to delete/sort/update with JPQL statements but I just can't make it work.

Comment: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete

Comment: @hoipolloi Thanks, I was looking at this one before, but again, I just can't figure out how can I make this work on a button click. I've mostly tried with queries based on this https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete but I end up with malformed querry error...